# I wrote a similar code as explained in tutorial but it does not work. Error included in description

Tags: express

```js
    let express=require("express") 
    let ourApp=express()
    ourApp.get('/',function(req,res) {
        res.send(
            `<form action="/answer" method="POST">
            <h1>What is the name of tallest mountain in the world?</h1>
            
        <input name="correct">
        <button>Click here to submiit</button>   </form>`
        ) }) 
    ourApp.post('/answer',function(req,res){
        if(req.body.correct=="everest")
                res.send("Thats a correct answer")
             } ) 
    ourApp.listen(3000)
```

Error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'correct' of undefined`

Comment: Your code is correct just needed to add middleware, posted my answer, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, Your app need a parser to parse request body.
You need a middle ware program to parse you request body. Try after installing body-parser.

After installing you can read req.body otherwise express will not recognize your req.body object,

```
let express = require("express");
let ourApp = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
ourApp.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);
ourApp.use(bodyParser.json());
ourApp.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send(
    `
        <form action="/answer" method="POST">
        <h1>What is the name of tallest mountain in the world?</h1>
    <input name="correct">
    <button>Click here to submiit</button>   </form>
    `
  );
});
ourApp.post("/answer", function (req, res) {
  if (req.body.correct.toLowerCase() == "everest") return res.send("<h2> Thats a correct answer </h2>");
  return res.send("<h2> Nope your are wrong </h2>");
});
ourApp.listen(3000);
```

Try this code. ourApp.use() - this one include body-parser middle ware to your app, Try to read about body-parser [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)  Made small modifications to your app :)

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**- `its not working because you need to add some middleware to parse the post data of the body.`

```
ourApp.use(express.json());
    ourApp.use(express.urlencoded());
```

*Tells how to parse application how to parse POST data*

My piece of Advice.

- Earlier versions of Express used to have a lot of middleware bundled with it. bodyParser was one of the middlewares that came it. When
  Express 4.0 was released they decided to remove the bundled
  middleware from Express and make them separate packages instead.
- The syntax then changed from app.use(express.json()) to
  app.use(bodyParser.json()) after installing the bodyParser module.
- bodyParser was added back to Express in release 4.16.0, because
  people wanted it bundled with Express like before. That means you
  don't have to use bodyParser.json() anymore if you are on the latest
  release. You can use express.json() instead.

Try this this works.

```
let express=require("express");
let ourApp = express();
ourApp.use(express.json());
ourApp.use(express.urlencoded());
ourApp.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send(
    `<form action="/answer" method="POST">
        <h1>What is the name of tallest mountain in the world?</h1>
        
    <input type="text" name="correct" id='jatin'> 
    <button>Click here to submiit</button>  </form> `
  );
});

ourApp.post("/answer", function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  if (req.body.correct == "everest") res.send("Thats a correct answer");
});

ourApp.listen(3000, function (req, res) {
  console.log("server started");
});
```